# Necessary and sufficient condition for tangential polygon to be cyclic

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, elementary-proofs, polygons

Can you prove or disprove the following claim?

> **Claim**. Let $A_1,A_2, \ldots ,A_n$ be the vertices of an $n$-sided [tangential polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_polygon) and let $B_1,B_2, \ldots ,B_n$ be the contact points of the inscribed circle and polygon sides such that $B_1$ lies on $A_1A_2$, $B_2$ lies on $A_2A_3$ ,etc. Denote by $H_1,H_2, \ldots,H_n$  the orthocenters of the triangles $\triangle A_1B_1B_n$, $\triangle A_2B_2B_1$,....,$\triangle A_nB_{n}B_{n-1}$ . Then the polygon is [cyclic](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicPolygon.html) if and only if $H_1,H_2,\ldots ,H_n$ are [concyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concyclic_points).

Picture for the case $n=6$:

[image]

GeoGebra applets that demonstrate this claim can be found [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/dawjjn7x) , [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/wzapgznq) and [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/kgb4yza4).

Comment: what is concyclic?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Concyclic points are the points that lie on the same circle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$H_i$ lies on the ray $IA_i$ and $IH_i\cdot IA_i=2r^2$ (where $r=IB_i$), since the midpoint of $IH_i$ is the midpoint of $B_iB_{i-1}$. Hence $H_i$ is the image of $A_i$ under the inversion with respect to center $I$ and radius $\sqrt{2}r$. Thus the result.